# Finding average based on Key

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table and values like this

```
create table Mytable (Cost money, NKey int, AvgBasedOnkey money)

insert into Mytable(Cost,NKey) values
    (20 ,1) ,
    (7  ,2) ,
    (7  ,2) ,
    (40 ,3) ,
    (40 ,3) ,
    (40 ,3) ,
    (5  ,3) ,
    (6  ,4) ,
    (8  ,4) `
```

[image]

I want the average cost to be updated in `AvgBasedOnKey` Column based on the `NKey` values as shown in the figure, For example, **:**

`(40 + 40 + 40 + 5) / 4 = 31.25` (because key number 3 occurred 4 times)

Help me with correct code

Comment: what is your approach so far? what did you try?

Comment: Do you want it to be updated regularly or just once with a query?

Comment: Don't add the AvgBasedOnKey column to your table, create a view instead to avoid data inconsistency!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SQL Server there is an easy way to do what you want. You can use the windowed version of `AVG` function:

```
SELECT Cost, NKey, AVG(Cost) OVER (PARTITION BY NKey)
FROM mytable
```

[**Demo here**](http://rextester.com/RSBSBC28269)

This version of [**`AVG`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/avg-transact-sql) is available from SQL Server 2008 onward. It simply calculates the average value of its argument over the partition specified in the `OVER` clause

Answer (score 2):

Try this solution with outer apply:

```
drop table if exists dbo.MyTable;

create table dbo.Mytable (Cost money, NKey int, AvgBasedOnkey money)

insert into dbo.Mytable(Cost,NKey) values
(20,1) ,
(7  ,2) ,
(7  ,2) ,
(40 ,3) ,
(40 ,3) ,
(40 ,3) ,
(5  ,3) ,
(6  ,4) ,
(8  ,4)


select
*
from dbo.Mytable mt
    outer apply (
            select
                avg(tmt.Cost) as AverageCost
            from dbo.Mytable tmt
            where tmt.NKey = mt.NKey
    ) t
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select  *, sum(Cost) over(partition by NKey) 
         / count(*) over(partition by NKey) as AvgBasedOnKey
from    Mytable
```

Comment: Why not use `AVG` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/avg-transact-sql

Answer (score 1):

The query below will produce a result of AvgBsedOnKey by Key which you can JOIN back to your original table

```
SELECT 
Key,
SUM(Cost)/COUNT(Cost) as AvgBasedOnKey
FROM Mytable
GROUP BY Key
```

Comment: Why not use `AVG` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/avg-transact-sql

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by updating the table using a join to a subquery which does the average calculation using [`AVG()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/avg-transact-sql).

```
create table MyTable (Cost money, NKey int, AvgBasedOnkey money null)

insert into MyTable ( Cost, NKey ) values
    (20,1) ,
    (7  ,2) ,
    (7  ,2) ,
    (40 ,3) ,
    (40 ,3) ,
    (40 ,3) ,
    (5  ,3) ,
    (6  ,4) ,
    (8  ,4) 


update t set t.AvgBasedOnkey = calc.AvgCost
    from MyTable t
    inner join (
        -- get average grouped on key
        select NKey, AVG(Cost) as AvgCost from MyTable group by NKey
    ) calc on t.NKey = calc.NKey

SELECT * FROM MyTable
```

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the averages, by key like this,

```
SELECT
            [Key],
            AVG([Cost]) [Average based on Key]
    FROM
            [MyTable]
    GROUP BY
            [Key];
```

If you really need to repeat those averages for every row (why) you can join back like this.

```
SELECT
            T.[Cost],
            T.[Key],
            A.[Avg] [Average based on Key]
    FROM
            [MyTable] T
        JOIN
            (
                SELECT
                            [Key],
                            AVG([Cost]) [Avg]
                    FROM
                            [MyTable]
                    GROUP BY
                            [Key]
            ) A
                ON A.[Key] = T.[Key];
```

Answer (score 0):

Shoould work easy like:

```
    UPDATE upd
       SET upd.AvgBasedOnkey = result.AvgCost
      FROM Mytable upd
INNER JOIN (
         SELECT AVG(Cost) AS AvgCost
               ,NKey
           FROM Mytable
         GROUP BY NKey   
           ) result
        ON result.NKey = upd.NKey
```